# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] выдает набор символов. Как расшифровать?

Tags: php

У меня на сайте при отправке юзером формы , мне приходит url с которого юзер пришел на сайт. Этот url я получаю через `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`
Так вот, стал приходить вот такой набор символов:

```
orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpibAvpwwIv5lE49bJlyNA8l2NUQqymJJ-PLt1Um-_0jsrYtXFt0csWNxzwfUmJPshLLfe_kfZjLCKjtoHHUUYYWZDwMYZEDv50SuYCW0m2GyA-ZH7TkP20aQe7aYm3plBsqxmEiks8Lhm1WkO7b-_YHUGXYA_IbJ-VKJ3urFw1lfdUbJBOA1LbgymeHykoIWsb-bzAPSgep2bAMMrO-tKbBtjFR5qsJIxjiOzBRt__hgLxKL6IwNKRbZqO7jjD4IWKN7E42P9mLOm6cO0ir0LIxrett0UfYmSM1967tMXpOs6ZwpZb2yWp5QQA7sbFo9Ul6IVcA9aJNF8rCL17nqyGQNsNB2aN7JNrmOHfnX6o8_iKLvyBS07qebszu5wdZDoPbhQRQVUXtA
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расскажите пожалуйста как это исправить/расшифровать и как вообще такое получается?

Comment: Похоже на base64. Проверить нет возможности. Замените скриншот на текст, тогда можно будет думать

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` может содержать все что угодно, а не только url, так как данные в нем задаются на стороне пользователя.

Comment: Это единственный случай???Возможно ошибка браузера.Кстати,если на форму можно попасть только через сам сайт,то будет $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] равный url вашего сайта.

Comment: если приходят и нормальные урл и такой - возможно кто-то неверно парсер настроил)

Comment: Дык это реферер робота) Бывает - блочить или не блочить надо думать - бывают роботы хорошие, бывают роботы плохие.

Answer (score 1):

шифровка подумал штирлиц...

скорее всего это редирект с https  зашифрованной страницы. либо антивиирус шифрует данные по перемещению пользователя, также могут быть боты,которые проверяют на вылетание системы, если оприделенный ответ пришел то сначит система подвержена атаке.

а если серьёзно, и более адекватно, то это кусок поискового запросса, чаще всего с яндекса в незашифрованной передаче данных.  их сильно много что парсилки  начало отбрасывают, либо записывают в другой ячейке и этот кусок попал на следующую запись.  Непереживайте, вот пойдут боты и кривые запросы, воттогда будет веселее, атак относитесь к этому как просто ошибочно записанные данные в БД(криво работал парсер/скрипт/урезала безопастность и т.п.)